# Google Play Services iOS SDK : Insufficient Permission

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

I did a bit of searching but didn't come up to any solution thus far. We have an iOS based game and we are trying to integrate Google Play Services. Followed the instructions on here:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart

I have the following permissions set in Google Dev Console: ( probably more then I need )

Drive API
Drive SDK
Google Play Game Management
Google Play Game Services
Google+ API
Google+ Domains API

When I try to sign in with my google email / password, it throws the following on the console even though it authenticates just fine.

This is how I am requesting for permissions and signing in:

```
GPGManager.sharedInstance().signInWithClientID(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, silently: false,
    withExtraScopes: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"
    ]
)
2014-12-20 15:49:17.352 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] -[PFCommandResult boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d974120
2014-12-20 15:52:55.403 TriviaBurst[24003:2679986] INFO: Auth operation started: SIGN IN
2014-12-20 15:52:55.404 TriviaBurst[24003:2679986] INFO: Auth operation SIGN IN finished with status VALID
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get name of an invalid Player
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get avatar URL of an invalid Player
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get id of an invalid Player
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get title of an invalid Player
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get current xp of an invalid Player
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get last level up timestamp of an invalid Player
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get current level of an invalid Player
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get level number of an invalid PlayerLevel
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get minimum xp of an invalid PlayerLevel
2014-12-20 15:52:55.408 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get maximum xp of an invalid PlayerLevel
2014-12-20 15:52:55.415 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get next level of an invalid Player
2014-12-20 15:52:55.416 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get level number of an invalid PlayerLevel
2014-12-20 15:52:55.416 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get minimum xp of an invalid PlayerLevel
2014-12-20 15:52:55.416 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] ERROR: Attempting to get maximum xp of an invalid PlayerLevel
2014-12-20 15:52:55.527 [Core] (Error) __49-[GPGService executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke:[main] Server Operation Failed [appstate.states.list]
    Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Insufficient Permission)
    Error Full: Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Insufficient Permission)" UserInfo=0x7a6bfd00 {error=Insufficient Permission, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x7a6be700: {message:"Insufficient Permission" code:403 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Insufficient Permission)}
2014-12-20 15:52:55.674 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] VERBOSE: Automatically seeded event cache.
2014-12-20 15:52:55.746 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] VERBOSE: Automatically seeded achievement cache.
2014-12-20 15:52:56.138 TriviaBurst[24003:2677075] WARNING: Could not automatically seed snapshot cache.
```

Comment: Looking more into this issue it seems like the issue is only seen on the simulator and not on an actual device.

Answer (score 1):

Check the OAuth 2.0 scope in authentication request. It should't be read-only. here is a calendar OAuth 2.0 example.

```
    // Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Google Calendar API.
    - (GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)createAuthController {
        GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authController;
        NSArray *scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopeCalendar, nil];
        authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
                          initWithScope:[scopes componentsJoinedByString:@" "]
                          clientID:kClientID
                          clientSecret:kClientSecret
                          keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                          delegate:self
                          finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    return authController;
}
```